# json list has not been assigned a key in spring

Tags: json, spring, rest

i am posting a JSON request to a REST service. service produce a json list (convert a bean list object to JSON). but it does not contain a key to parse this list at client side.
can i parse json list without a key on client side or how can i assign  key to this list.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getScheduleTrip", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json" )  
public @ResponseBody List<ResponseParametersOfRest> getScheduleTrip(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody RequestParametersOfRest requestRest) {  
    List<ResponseParametersOfRest> responseRest = null;
    try{
        System.out.println("hello");
        responseRest = serviceScheduledTripJDBCTemplate.getTripDetails(requestRest);
    }catch(Exception ee){
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseRest;  


}
```

and the output is

```
[{"companyID":8,"deviceID":18,"vehicleID":18,"personnelID":172,"startCity":"Jaipur","startState":"ND","startDate":"2013-08-14","startTime":"10:55:00","endCity":"ajmer","endState":"CM","endDate":"2013-08-05","endTime":"10:55:00","manifestNo":"7568956","initialCargoWeight":"0","yardLocation":"","loadStatus":false,"scheduledTripUserID":42,"instructions":null,"scheduledTripStatus":false,"receivedDateTime":"2013-08-05 10:58:33.0","serverScheduledTripID":42,"deleteStatus":false,"errorCode":0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to parse the array without having it being assigned to a property but it's not recommended.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

It's preferable to have it assigned to a property. To do this you could create a new class e.g.

```
class ListJsonResource {
    private final List<Object> list;

    public ListJsonResource(List<Object> list) { ... }
    public List<Object> getList() { ... }
}
```

That will wrap your list and altering the output.

```
public @ResponseBody ListJsonResource getScheduleTrip(@RequestBody RequestParametersOfRest requestRest) {  
    List<ResponseParametersOfRest> responseRest = null;
    try{
        responseRest = serviceScheduledTripJDBCTemplate.getTripDetails(requestRest);
    }catch(Exception ee){
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ListJsonResource(responseRest);  
}
```